# why is this for loop not getting called?

Tags: objective-c, for-loop

Hello and thanks for the help

Why is this for loop not getting called.  (contents is an nsmutableArray)

```
 NSString *setBiz = [[NSString alloc]init];
setBiz = @"MomAndPop";
 NSLog(@"??????????listby???????????%@\n",setBiz);


for (NSDictionary *key in self.contents) {
    NSLog(@"hi inside loopppp");  //I never see this ????????

     NSString *c = [key objectForKey:@"BizName"];
    NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", key];  //random test 


    if ([c isEqualToString:setBiz]) {
        NSLog(@"gotch you");
    }

}
```

Comment: `NSString *setBiz = [[NSString alloc] init]; setBiz = @"MomAndPop";` looks nasty.

Comment: this is just for testing.....I plan on setting the string from a webservice call.  If there is a better way I would be happy to learn...I'm only 6months in on objective c.  Thanks.

Comment: The ` NSString *setBiz = [[NSString alloc]init];` is total nonsense if you are going to immediately set it to a different string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most likely answer is that `self.contents` has no elements inside of it.

Place this before your loop to output the number of elements in the loop:

`NSLog(@"self.contents.count: %lu", self.contents.count);`

Comment: you are correct.  NSLog Count = 0.   Not sure what I missed I called the plist and NSLog contents all the data shows up in my console....???  do I have to initialize somewhere ????  thanks for the clue.

Comment: Please post the code where you create/update the self.contents.

Comment: NSString *filePathz = [self dataFilePath];
contents = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePathz];
NSLog(@"??????????listby???????????%@\n",contents);  ........  This is how I fill "contents"....just before my loop.

Comment: This gets tricky because this problem deals with how you've structured your code, but it looks like you are setting a local variable `contents` instead of the property `contents` replace `contents = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWith...` with `self.contents = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWith...`

Again, this might not be the problem, but it is hard to determine with little information.

Comment: Daniel...you have turned water into wine.  It works.  Many many thanks.  Sorry to bother you on a weekend.  If I can trouble you one more time......what the hell does this magic work "self" do in Object-c do and when or why should I use it.

Comment: @AhabLives it's not the word `self`, it's the `.` (dot) operator, and it specifies property access. Google `Objective-C properties`.